# creating https connection in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, security, https, spring-integration

I need to create a HTTPS connection with a URL from spring integration http outbound gateway , I downloaded the certificate from URL using Mozilla Firefox its a .cer file and configured it in spring bean as shown in http://www.programering.com/a/MDN4czNwATY.html

For both trust store and key store I am using "changeit" password

Upon running the application I am getting java.io.IOException : Invalid key store format

Initially I tried accessing https://www.google.com

If any one has already faced this issue then please let know the solution.

I have also tried setting :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\SWDTOOLS\\jdk1.7.0_21-x64\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\repos\\C:\repos\thawtePrimaryRootCA.crt");
        System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS" );
        System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");
```

And installing the key store in JVM trust store
belowe is the spring configuration I have used to use https connection:

```
<bean id="trustStore" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <props>
                <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStore">
                    ${key.store.truststore}
                </prop>
                <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword">${key.store.password}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="keystore" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <props>
                <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStore">
                    ${key.store.file.thwate}
                </prop>
                <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword">${key.store.password}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

this is my stacktrace:
   Exception in thread "main"

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [https://edw.morningstar.com/login.aspx]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:284)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:98)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:44)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:160)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:125)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:44)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:239)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:300)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:269)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:260)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.amg.fds.UniverseMain.main(UniverseMain.java:91)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); nested exception is java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:384)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:258)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:198)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:409)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleClientHttpRequest.java:73)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:438)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1262)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:97)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:121)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:333)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.openConnection(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:91)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:434)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultKeyManager(SSLContextImpl.java:610)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:495)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1238)
    ... 50 more
```

url I am trying to access is :

```
https://edw.morningstar.com/login.aspx
```

I downloaded the certificates using firfox browser

Comment: you should tell us how you imported the cer into your keystore. Did you use portecle for this ?

Comment: I have updated the question with how i have configured truststore and keystore

Comment: I guess `C:\\repos\\C:\repos\thawtePrimaryRootCA.crt` will not work. With which command did you add the certificate to the keystore ?

Comment: Besides that: you set a type `JKS` and provide a `.cer`.

Comment: You need to provide a JKS store, not the .crt file. That is what the error message says. Also, there is no need to override javax.net.ssl.trustStore with cacerts, as it already is the default trust store. What you need to do is import that certificate into the store using: "keytool -import -alias YOURALIAS -file FILENAME.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit"

Answer (score -2):

Most easy way in your case is ignore the certificate (if the security is not your problem). Check the snip code below for an example:

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String authType) {
        return true;
    }
};
SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(acceptingTrustStrategy, 
SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme("https", 8443, sf));
ClientConnectionManager ccm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(registry);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm);

String urlOverHttps = "https://localhost:8443/spring-security-rest-basic-auth/api/bars/1";
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(urlOverHttps);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);
```

For more you can ask me or use this refer: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl

Comment: I cannot ignore certificate, that is not recomended way as per our client

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it recommends an approach with potentially severe security risks, and doesn't sufficiently disclose this.